# How to prevent shower water from leaking from the side of glass shower door

Tags: bathroom, shower

Shower water often leaks from the side gap of my glass shower door (see attached). I already replaced the old undersweep with new one that seals it better from the bottom, but it seems shower splash still comes out of the hinge gap on the side, which can seep under the flooring and show up as a water spot on the ceiling downstairs in the living room. I would highly appreciate effective ways to block the shower splash from exiting the shower room. It’s really poor shower room design IMO, as I never had such problem in my previous residences, but I don’t have the energy to replace it completely. Thanks!

[image: corner of shower door where water leaks]

[image: door when closed and shower going on inside]

Comment: I have installed similar doors that had a rubber seal on the side just like the one you have on the bottom of your door. When the door is closed it makes contact with the wall.

Answer (score 2):

did you ever resolve this? If not, then may I suggest that you need a seal that runs down the hinge side of the shower door.

It looks like you have 8mm glass SO you would use a PCR8 From CR Laurence.
[image: Shower seal]

You can [find them here](https://www.shower-glass.co.uk/translucent-bulb-seal-for-8mm-glass/)

They are a simply push on seal that you can run from the top of the glass right down to the bottom, you would have to cut the seals where the hinges are but thats about as technical as you get.

Lee

Comment: Thank you for your detailed advice! I thought about buying a wider undersweep as you suggested but haven’t had time to follow through with it. Will try it this month! Also my wife suggested that if I open the door outward after shower there is actually less chance of spilling. That seemed indeed the case but does not complete solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm skeptical that this damage is all coming from the hinge side of the glass door, that is unless your shower sprays directly on it.

Could you confirm that as the water runs down the inside face of your shower door, and onto the bottom sweep, that it runs into your shower and down the drain?

I have a feeling that if you pour water on the inside of the door, that the door sweep actually channels the water to the lowest spot, which is the hinge side of the door since it's not hung perfectly level. From there it runs outside your shower and on the floor, instead of to the inside of your shower and down the drain.

Upload a picture of the door closed, it's probably going to be obvious that's what's going on.

Your shower door is installed too closely to the outside edge, and should be about 2-3 inches further in. The solution is to remove the hinges from the wall and remount the door further into the shower. I'm pretty sure you don't have to do anything to stop it from coming through the hinge side if you do that.

It might even be possible to flip the hinges 180 degrees and reuse the same holes. That would only get you 1", but that might be all you need.

Comment: The OP state in his question **"Shower water often leaks from the side gap of my glass shower door"**  How is moving the door further away from the wall, thereby making a **larger gap**, going to *help keep water from getting through the gap* ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan I meant move the door closer to the drain, not further from the wall.

Comment: I see, you mean move it into the shower space so it sits more *over the center of the curb* as opposed to close to the outside. That would help. I would  also build a little damn out silicone at the bottom of the gap to keep any water from flowing out.

Comment: Thanks! I think you have a point. Will try to block from the bottom first